# Multiple UIButtons shown vertically with different UIButton names

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uibutton

I have 3 different buttons, and I am using for loop to display it in my UIView. The problem is, there is only one button shown.

```
float yButton = 50.0;

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, yButton + 70.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
    [button setTag:i];
}
```

Also, how do I set the button titles to A, B, and C (since there are only 3 buttons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You give all of the buttons the same frame. You need to increment the `y` origin.

At the end of the loop, do this:

```
yButton += 50; // pick a value that meets your needs.
```

To set the titles, create an array with the three titles:

```
NSArray *titles = @[ @"A", @"B", @"C" ];
```

then in the loop:

```
[button setTitle:titles[i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: @Jahm Update your question with your actual code. Also see my update for setting the titles.

Comment: thanks! There was something missing ;) By the way, the NSArray should be inside the for loop?

Comment: Thanks! The buttons are shown correctly with their corresponding name. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

You give all buttons the same frame:

```
telcoButton.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, yButton + 70.0, 160.0, 40.0);
```

You probably want to do this:

```
telcoButton.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, (yButton * i) + 70.0, 160.0, 40.0);
```

Comment: Actually, you would want `yButton * (i + 1) + 70.0` assuming the current code was correct for the 1st button.